# Protecting a chmodded 0777 cache directory?

Tags: php, security, web-server, permissions, .htaccess

A website I'm developing requires several directories to have their permissions set to 0777. The directories are used as cache directories for HTML and PHP files generated by the website.

The website doesn't require any "upload" scripts for users to upload content.

Will a hacker be able to upload files to the 0777 directories without the aid of an upload script on my website?

How vulnerable are the 0777 cache directories? What's the best way to protect them in this situation?

Comment: Why the downvote? I'm a new user here and I'm still learning about how to correctly set up a website/webserver.

Comment: Probably (wasn't me, so don't know for sure) because this question maps directly to "is my PHP code secure?", which isn't something we can answer for you.

Comment: "A website I'm developing requires several directories to have their permissions set to 0777." -- no it doesn't.  Never.  Ever.  *EVER*.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I think it's not a good practice to leave any web folder 0777, but a lot of people are doing it.

One way to increase the security is to run the web site as an dedicated user and then you can get ride of the writing permission for the others. Although that can make the security a bit better, still at the end of the day it comes to how secure the code is.

Comment: A lot of people are doing it? Certainly not a lot of **competent** people.

Comment: I agree but what can you do ? :)